# Plot in R: X axis sorted by quantity?

Tags: r, bar-chart

I would like to build a barplot with the R software to describe my data. 
For example. I want to shop the number of observation per species.

Is it possible to sort the X axis by the number of observation instead of alphabetical order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
set.seed(24)
v1 <- sample(LETTERS[1:6],40, replace=TRUE)
tbl <- table(v1)
tbl1 <- sort(tbl, decreasing=TRUE)
barplot(tbl1)
```